# send java script function parameter to ASP.NET MVC helper method

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have a Ajax form in my asp.net mvc application, which has a onSuccess callback as below:

```
function onSuccessReport(context)
        {
            $('reportChart').empty();

            var line1=@Html.GetStrippedString(context.Expenses);
}
```

I defined a html helper which accept an string an manipulte it and return a string.

What I pass to onSuccessReport, is a json result which has a structure like this:

[image]

But I cant send context.Expenses and the application throws syntax error.

How can I send a javascript variable to my helper?

Thanks

**Edited:**
The error in my view

****Error   1   The name 'context' does not exist in the current context****

C# method

```
json = json.Replace("\"Date\":", string.Empty);

            json = json.Replace("\"Total\":", string.Empty);

            json = json.Replace('}', ']');

            json = json.Replace('{', '[');

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(json);
```

Comment: What's the syntax error you get?

Comment: I edited the question and wrote the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can send javascript values over to the server side if you use Ajax.  Instead of using your helper method the way you are, just change it into an action within the Controller to return you some Json (could just be a string, number, object, etc, etc).  Here is an example of what you might try out.

View

```
function onSuccessReport(context)
    {
        $('reportChart').empty();
        var expenses = context.Expenses;
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetStrippedString", "ControllerName")', { expenses: expenses }, function (data) {
            //pending what you pass back as data, do whatever with it
            alert(data);
        });
 }
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult GetStrippedString(string expenses)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    //Do something to string
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I declared a java variable to hold the data from GetStrippedString and I use that variable in some other function. I declraed the function after calling  getJSON, but it seems that geJson is being called after that function

Comment: Can you post an example?  I want to try and trace out the logic and see when everything should be called to make sure the other function isn't getting hit first.

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was with async ajax call

Comment: Ah yes, that would be troublesome.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing client side code (javascript) with server side code (HtmlHelper). You cannot pass client side variables to server side helpers. If the `context` variable is known only on the client then you will have to write a client side javascript function instead of server side helper. So move to logic you wrote in this `Html.GetStrippedString` helper into a javascript function that you could call from your script.

Comment: Im not so familiar with java script so cant you help writing a replace function like the C# method I explained my question?

Comment: What is this function supposed to return given the shown input?